# .NET Maui BindingContext losed (not working)

Tags: maui, binding-context

I have a few issues. I created an application on Xamarin and I started converting it into Maui. But I have some issues. **In Xamarin I deliberately choosed to declared in the App.cs the partial class used for bindingcontext (SidebarVM) for example**.
By doing so, when I can easily access from other pages or other viewmodels a value inside the "SidebarVM" partial class by simply requesting it => `bool myboolean = App.SidebarVM.MyValueRequested;`

I use CommunityToolkit.Mvvm in the partial class used for the BindingContext.

In the contentpage.cs, I declared the bindingcontext as follow `BindingContext = App.SidebarVM;`

In the contentpage.xaml, I declared the bindingcontext by using `x:DataType=sb:SidebarVM`

Everything worked perfectly in xamarin.forms, however in  .net MAUI I have the following issues come accross:

1. The bindingcontext lose track of value OnPropertyChanged even if the value is changed
2. The User interface never update due to the 1st issue.

Do any expert on the subject have a solution a guidance to the described issue?

Comment: More code is required so we can reproduce it.

Comment: I published a few minutes ago a small project which will showcase all current bugs. Make sure to play the video inside the project to see how it goes. https://github.com/flaubertlekhem/MauiTestCore

Comment: What happens if you use [ObservableProperty] annotation, and let the MVVM write the code instead of you?

Comment: The following error shows and I do not know how it happens or how to solve it since I never had this in Xamarin ever. Error CS0229 Ambiguity between 'AuthenticateVM.ButtonsVisible' and 'AuthenticateVM.ButtonsVisible'

Comment: When deleted the public attribute of the boolean and only using [ObservableProperty] and the private attribute, the error disappear (previous comment). However, the problem is not solved at all. It continues to required the page to change the size to be displayed in the user interface.

Comment: Your code shouldn't have uploaded completely, at least I didn't find the `sln` file.

Comment: Hello @JessieZhang-MSFT The code have been updated. The sln and the app with the mauiprogram have been included. Please check it out.

Comment: I cannot find code `BindingContext = App.SidebarVM;` in your app.  How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Sorry for the inconvenience. I just push the project, clone it and test  it. Can you check it?

Comment: I could build and deploy your app to my emulator. But I could not find `BindingContext = App.SidebarVM;`.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I think that he uploaded separate project to demonstrate the issue. In ViewModels/AuthenticateVM, he has show password property (and others), that do not seem to work well. This file in his repo is a video to demonstrate it MauiTestCore/MauiTestCore/MauiTest bugs.mp4

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Sorry but the reference 'App.SidebarVM' is in another demo project that I did not upload on github. In the project uploaded, please look at the reference 'App.AuthenticateVM' in the App.cs class of the project MauiTestCore (https://github.com/flaubertlekhem/MauiTestCore/blob/main/MauiTestCore/App.xaml.cs)

Comment: I added a button to page `Login.xaml` and added a clicked event for it. I also tried to change the value of `ButtonsVisible`, and the UI could refresh itself.

Comment: This is why it is strange. Has you can see it does not change when I try it. I run the application on Windows 10 version 20h22 Build 19045.3448. Is it possible for you to confirm the issue on this system?

Comment: The UI could also update after I deployed it to windows. The code I used is `private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        App.AuthenticateVM.ButtonsVisible = !App.AuthenticateVM.ButtonsVisible;
    }
`

Comment: I tested on windows 11.

Comment: There is something I do not understand. I tested the code on my windows 11 machine and the same behavior presented in the video occured. When you said "The UI could also updated after I deployed it to windows" what do you mean? I only try to debug the solution. Even launch the application deployed but the behavior persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is triggering but the actual solution to this issue is to always create your Maui pages inside `<VerticalStackLayout>...</VerticalStackLayout>` otherwise, this issue happens.

Also, AbsoluteLayout have a big issue in .net maui. The use is really practical if you want to display something on top of the page, but this bug is critical for UI experience.